# Is it still meaningful to have 29.97fps under ATSC standard?

Tags: framerate

According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GJUM6pCpew), we use 29.97fps under NTSC standard.

But now we have ATSC standard, do we still need 29.97fps in order to broadcast under ATSC?

Is it still meaningful to have a newly created video with 29.97fps?

Answer (score 2):

The non-integer HD frame rates (interlaced 59.94 and progressive 29.97) exist [to facilitate easy downconversion to Standard Definition (SD)](http://www.hdhead.com/?p=108) that must operate at 29.97. There is no technical reason that the non-integer frame rates must be used in ATSC or other SMPTE 292 systems, just the compatibility reason.

Comment: Why must SD delivery be at 29.97? SD delivery is still digital; there's no analog broadcasting to be compatible with.

Comment: According to the [ITU](https://www.itu.int/net4/ITU-D/CDS/DSO2019/Map_Filter.asp?Country=&Standard=&Region=&Compression=&Status=), there are 19 countries that have not started digital transitions and 63 countries with in progress transitions. Even in countries that have completed the transition, it is very expensive and complicated to switch existing hardware (mostly SDI-based) systems from non-integer to integer frame rates. As facilities are rebuilt and switch to IP (2110), it will be more feasible to eliminate the non-integer frame rates.

Comment: How many of those countries are NTSC? At any (frame) rate, it's unfortunate that we're still saddled with this crap.